# cherrypy, serve css file, wrong path

Tags: python, path, cherrypy, static-content

I have an issue to load my css on a html page managed with CherryPy.
This is my situation:

```
class HelloWorld(object):
   @cherrypy.expose
   def index(self):
     return "Hello world!"


   @cherrypy.expose
   def sc(self):
     Session = sessionmaker()
     session = Session(bind=engine)
   ...
   ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld(),config={
'/':
{'tools.staticdir.root': True,
'tools.staticdir.root': "Users/mypc/Desktop/data"},
'/css':
{ 'tools.staticdir.on':True,'tools.staticdir.dir':"/css" }, 
'/style.css':
{ 'tools.staticfile.on':True,
'tools.staticfile.filename':"/style.css"}
})
```

When I launch my script there is wrtten:

```
CherryPy Checker:
dir is an absolute path, even though a root is provided.
'/css' (root + dir) is not an existing filesystem path.
section: [/css]
root: 'Users/mypc/Desktop/data'
dir: '/css'
```

but root + dir is the right path (Users/mypc/Desktop/data/css)
Where I'm wrong and why I cannot open my css by browser?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [the relevant documentation section](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basics.html#serving-a-whole-directory). It says:

> CherryPy always requires the absolute path to the files or directories it will serve. 
>   If you have several static sections to configure but located in the same root 
>   directory, you can use the following shortcut... `tools.staticdir.root`

In other works, when you provide `tools.staticdir.root`, all underlying `tools.staticdir.dir` entries must not be absolute, i.e. start with slash, which is what the CherryPy Checker is warning you about.

The following is enough. Just put you CSS files the directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import os

import cherrypy


path   = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8
  },
  '/css' : {
    'tools.staticdir.on'  : True,
    'tools.staticdir.dir' : os.path.join(path, 'css')
  }
}


class App:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    return 'Hello world!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I need only to add the root section to the config!